# MVC4 Pattern for receiving password reset token

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, passwords

Trying to get password reset functionality in place.  This will be for a user who has not and cannot log in to the system.  I think I'm close but it doesn't feel right:

I have a ResetPassword method/view...it simply asks for the user's email address, does not confirm an account to the user but if one exists, sends email with link+token.  That all works fine.

The next part is where my questions are....I receive the password token with this method (via the user's email link being clicked):

```
[HttpGet]
    public ActionResult ReceiveResetToken(string token)
    {
        try
        {
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(token))
            {
                var username = (from u in db.Users
                                    where u.Userid == WebSecurity.GetUserIdFromPasswordResetToken(token)
                                    select u.Email).ToString();

                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(username))
                {
                    WebSecurity.ConfirmAccount(token);

                }
            }
            RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            throw;
        }
    }
```

I'm missing something obvious here.  The method isn't complete because I keep rethinking it...get the username, confirm the account, somehow log them in without knowing what their password is, redirect to change password page?  Doesn't feel right.

So then I thought maybe pass along the hidden username with a ViewBag to the change dialogue...doesn't feel right either.  I'd like a more elegant approach, receive the token, ask the username for the new password, update db and login.  What is the pattern for receiving a password reset token?

EDIT -------

So as I am continuing to search for answers, I came across this little gem.  Apparently there is a WebSecurity.ResetPassword method that accepts the token and a new password.  This feels like the right path, no need to worry about logins, just change it and redirect to login...I'll finish up the code and post a solution as this seems to be a popular and often unanswered question on SO.

If anyone could confirm that I'm on the right path or post any thoughts on adding elegance to the pattern that'd be cool

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question in case it helps anyone.

1. Provide a form asking for email address to send password reset link
2. Use `WebSecurity.GeneratePasswordResetToken(email, 1440)` to generate token
3. Send email to user with link pointing to a token receiving method
4. Write an HttpGet method to receive the token and display newPassword form
5. The form posts the token and the new password model to a method that uses WebSecurity.ResetPassword(token, newPassword)
6. redirect to login

Haven't written it all out yet but I think this is the way to do it properly

Answer (score 2):

It's a right path !

for me,

User give his email and i send him a token who is generate an `GUID` and i have `passwordResetTokenDate` who take a date when user asked the reset. (token is valid 48hours)

in email, there is a link with token and i give him a token, if when he click and something is wrong, he can copy pasted the token in textbox or re-clicking on the link

when he click on the link, i check the token and the date and `passwordResetTokenDate` if all is right, there is two textbox and user enter 2 times his new password.

when he save his password, i logged him.

`WebSecurity.ResetPassword` do the job !

here an example : (i have a custom websecurity with custom provider)

```
   [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult ForgotMyPassword(string confirmation, string username)
    {
        username = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(username);
        ViewBag.Succeed = false;
        SetPasswordViewModel Fmp = new SetPasswordViewModel(username,confirmation);
        return View(Fmp);
    }

    //
    // POST: /Account/ForgotMyPassword

    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult ForgotMyPassword(SetPasswordViewModel model)
    {
        ViewBag.Succeed = false;
        if (ModelState.isValid)
        {
            ViewBag.Succeed = WebSecurity.ResetPassword(model.UserName, model.PasswordResetToken, model.Password.NewPassword);
        }


        if (!ViewBag.Succeed)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("","something"); //something
        }
        return View(model);
    }
```

Comment: In your example you are passing model.UserName as the first parm to ResetPassword()?  Otherwise, looks very close to what I will do

Comment: It is not considered a best security practice to have reset tokens valid for more than an hour or two. 48 hours seem to long a duration.

Comment: Yes, because i have my own websecurity [you can see an version here] (http://codefirstmembership.codeplex.com/). Many users on my website doesn't click on the link in 2hours

Answer (score 1):

This is how it should work (as implemented in [ASP Security Kit](http://ASPSecurityKit.net/features#forgot))

1. User clicks on forgot password link (which opens /account/forgot for example)
2. On this page, you ask user for his userName (which could be his email).
3. You check whether that user exists. If yes, you generate a reset token, saving it in the database for that username and send out an email to that user with a link (http://yourdomain.com/account/confirm/[tokenHere])
4. You display user a message something like "if you have an account with this username, you will receive an email with instructions to reset your password shortly." but you don't login user on this page because you just asked him for his username!
5. User receives the email, clicks on the link and the reset password page opens (/account/confirm/[tokenHere])
6. On this page, user needs to fill password and confirm password fields. Once done you will redirect user to login page (you may argue that you can directly sign in user once he resets his password; but redirecting to login seems to be the standard practice  followed on most sites.)

Comment: yes, thanks, step 6 is where I was having problems.  The WebSecurity.ResetPassword method was what I was missing...with that you can auth the token and assign new password the the user without ever caring who the user is